# url mapping to specific plugin in grails

Tags: grails

I have a grails app, which is split into three.

- The grailsapp itself
- Plugin #1
- Plugin #2

I need to create a URL mapping, such that /p1 delegates to plugin #1 controllers and /p2 delegates to plugin #2 controllers. First of all because they are semantically different, but also because they have some overlapping controller names.

Can that be achieved automatically by mapping or do I have to manually provide all mappings?

```
    static mappings = {
    "/p1/$controller/$action/$id?(.$format)?" {
        constraints {
            // use only controllers from p1
        }
    }
    "/p2/$controller/$action/$id?(.$format)?" {
        constraints {
            // use only controllers from p2
        }
    }
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // only use app controllers??
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the Grails [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) regarding URL mappings to see how you can specify a mapping to a plugin for controller resolution. From the documentation:

> It is allowed for an application to use a plugin which provides a
>   controller with the same name as a controller provided by the
>   application and for neither of the controllers to define a namespace
>   property as long as the controllers are in separate packages. For
>   example, an application may include a controller named
>   com.accounting.ReportingController and the application may use a
>   plugin which provides a controller named
>   com.humanresources.ReportingController. The only issue with that is
>   the URL mapping for the controller provided by the plugin needs to be
>   explicit in specifying that the mapping applies to the
>   ReportingController which is provided by the plugin.
>
> See the following example.
>
> ```
> static mappings = {
>     "/accountingReports" {
>         controller = "reporting"
>     }
>     "/humanResourceReports" {
>         controller = "reporting"
>         plugin = "humanResources"
>     }
> }
> ```

I suspect in your example your URL mappings might look something like this:

```
"/p1/$controller/$action/$id?(.$format)?" {
    plugin = "p1"
    constraints {
        // use only controllers from p1
    }
}
"/p2/$controller/$action/$id?(.$format)?" {
    plugin = "p2"
    constraints {
        // use only controllers from p2
    }
}
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    constraints {
        // only use app controllers??
    }
}
```

All though, the wording of the documentation does state **the controller provided by the plugin needs to be explicit in specifying the mapping** which would indicate to me that dynamic mappings such as the above may not work.

Comment: I see what you mean. I read that section without spotting the 'plugin' line. Let me test it out.

Comment: Just a reminder to mark this as correct if it worked - its never too late ;-)